# How to transform that pseudocode into java code?

Tags: java, opencv, pseudocode

I found out a piece of pseudocode that I wish to try using opencv; however, I'm not fully familiar with the dictionary used in it.

Below, is the first part of it:

```
stackedPixels ← ∅
for all pixelRow in image do 
    for all pixel in pixelRow do 
        stackedPixels ← stackedPixels ∪ pixel   
    end for 
end for
```

1. As showed above **stackedPixels** is an array?
2. In the loop, what the union **stackedPixels ∪ pixel** represents?

Could some one help me to understand it?

Comment: I believe it's a set, initialized to the empty set, and then union-ed with each pixel.

Comment: Starting with an empty list of pixels, loop through every pixel in every row adding each pixel to the list, is what I gather.

Comment: Pseudo-code is a way of communicating an algorithm.  You need to understand the algorithm you are trying to implement.You need to know 1) how to program in Java (do you?) and 2) what this code is trying to do (do you?)

Comment: The ∅, ∪, ← should be thought of in terms of their meaning. There isn't some rule book that you can directly translate from. For example, with the union, that could be just adding two Set<Pixel> together.

Comment: Please don't thank people in comments.  Vote their comments or answers up!

Comment: @DaleWilson I know how to program in Java and what the result expected by using the code. I'm kind of lost because I'm using opencv, now I think I can move on!

Comment: @DaleWilson I cannot vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `stackedPixels` could be an array or any sort of Collection that can store the `pixel` objects.
2. `stackedPixels ∪ pixel` represents appending the current `pixel` to `stackedPixels`